# how to show php session varrible in angular js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have 3 pages

1:login.php

    if Successfully Logged in...
    $_SESSION['user']=$userxData['id'];}

2:getuserdetails.php

```
session_start();
require_once '../database.php';
$query=$db_con->prepare("select * from userz WHERE cust_id=:usk");
$query->execute(array(":usk"=>$userxData['id']=$_SESSION['user']));
$user = array();
if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
$row = $query->fetchObject();
  $user[] = $row->{"mail"};
echo $json_response = json_encode($user);
```

}

3:app.js

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('theController', function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.loadCategory = function(){
        $http.get("ajax/getCategory.php")
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.categories = data;
            }) }
     $scope.things = function(){
        $http.post("ajax/getProducts.php", {'cat_id':$scope.cate})
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.productz = data;
            });}
  $http.get('getuserdetails.php').success(function(user){
       if (user){
            $scope.user = user;
        }
    });
```

The problem is session variable displays only when i refresh the page. Some help Please.

Comment: Could you provide us with the HTML where you try to show the variable? Secondly, did you verify the `getuserdetails.php` response contains the data you expect?

Comment: yap getuserdetails.php contains that data.         html                                            `<html ng-app="myApp">
<body ng-controller="PosController">
                       <h6><span class="label label-primary"ng-if="user">{{user}}</span></h6>
</html></body>`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably changing the $scope outside of the angular $digest. 
Try to do this:

```
$http.get('getuserdetails.php').success(function(user){
    $scope.$apply(function(){ 
         if(user)
             $scope.user = user;
    })
});
```

Comment: I'd consider it quite unlikely that the digest cycle doesn't trigger after a http get. Normally it does.